# Accessing an Azure Database for MySQL Single Server from outside Azure

Tags: python, mysql, azure, ip, whitelist

Moving this question from DevOps Stack Exchange where it got only 5 views in 2 days:

---

I would like to query an **Azure Database for MySQL Single Server**.

I normally interact with this database using a universal database tool (**dBeaver**) installed onto an **Azure VM**. Now I would like to interact with this database using **Python** *from outside Azure*. Ultimately I would like to write an API (FastAPI) allowing multiple users to connect to the database.

I ran a simple test from a Jupyter notebook, using **SQLAlchemy** as my ORM and specifying the pem certificate as a connection argument:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

cnx = create_engine('mysql://XXX', connect_args={"ssl": {"ssl_ca": "mycertificate.pem"}})
```

I then tried reading data from a specific table (*e.g.* mytable):

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable', cnx)
```

Alas I ran into the following error:

> 'Client with IP address 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX' is not allowed to connect to
> this MySQL server'.

According to my colleagues, a way to fix this issue would be to whitelist my IP address.
While this may be an option for a couple of users with static IP addresses I am not sure whether it is a valid solution in the long run.

**Is there a better way to access an Azure Database for MySQL Single Server from outside Azure?**

Comment: It is very common to allow IP ranges to connect to your Azure mySQL database, you can do this via Azure portal. Alternately, you can open up access to any IP range, then only hope your connection string is securely stored in Azure KeyVault and used by your python code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Anand. Whitelisting an IP range sounds like an acceptable solution then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to `whitelist` the IP address ranges(s) in the Azure portal for your MySQL database resource. This is a well accepted and secure approach.